# How can I check if any member of an array is greater than 9000

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to make a script which takes action, if one member of the entire array is greater than 9000.

```
$all = 1,10,999,1990,2002,9101,5000,12,500
    foreach($cauta in $all){
        if($cauta -gt 7000){
            Send-MailMessage -To me@myemail.com -From alert@myemail.com -Subject "CRITICAL load" 
        }
        else{
            Send-MailMessage -To me@myemail.com -From alert@myemail.com -Subject "OK load" 
        }
}
```

The problem is, with this foreach, it sends me emails continuously.
I need to receive an email with "OK" or "CRITICAL" status:
If one of the array members is greater than 9000 -> send one email with critical status.
If all members of the array are below 9000 -> send one email with ok status.

Comment: Just use `Measure-Object`? `if( ($all | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum -gt 7000){"critical"}else{"ok"}`. So it is critical if there is at least one above 7000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need the loop.   Powershell's relational operators work on arrays.   So for example you can type:

```
$all = 1,10,999,1990,2002,9101,5000,12,500 
if ($all -gt 9000) { echo "too big..." }
```

If you do

```
$large = $all -ge 5000
if ($large) { echo "These are too big: $large" }
```

$large will get assigned an array containing just the values greater than or equal to 5000.  Powershell treats any non-empty array as trueish, making the first example work...

Comment: Wow...this simple answer blows me. I didn't expect that to work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that this works for integer arrays but the presence of strings, or other objects, can mess with it.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a perfect case for [`Measure-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh849965.aspx). Using the `-Maximum` switch we can return the largest array element, since they are integers.

```
if(($all | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum -gt 7000){
    "critical"
} else {
    "ok"
}
```

No sense looping checking all the elements individually.

Also, as wOxxOm reminds me, `-gt` works as an array operator. You can use it just like this...

```
$all -gt 7000
```

What that will do is return all elements that are greater than 7000. Null is returned if there is no match. If you test that result as a boolean to have the same effect.

```
if($all -gt 7000){
    "critical"
} else {
    "ok"
}
```

Be careful with this approach as if there are string in this array it might return them as well. Using `Measure-Object` will account for that and treat integer strings as integers. Can still fail with real string to all around be aware of your data types!

Comment: Why not `if ($all -gt 7000) { ... }` ?

Comment: Apparently `-gt` and `measure -maximum` give different results if there are numbers-as-strings in the array. `@('8', 7000) -gt 7000` will say the 8 is bigger than 7000 and go critical, whereas `@('8',7000) | measure -Maximum` will say the 7000 is the maximum and everything's OK. (I suspect that doesn't matter to this question, but I'm surprised to see them behave differently)

Comment: Hmm. I suppose you could take this farther and explicitly cast to int array before the comparison. I will add a disclaimer to be safe

Comment: [int[]]$all
Well, for this instead I transform it to int, so that string issue will not happen :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$all = 1, 10, 999, 1990, 2002, 9101, 5000, 12, 500
$subject = "OK load"
foreach ($cauta in $all)
{
    if ($cauta -gt 7000)
    {
        $subject = "CRITICAL load"
    }
}
Send-MailMessage -To me@myemail.com -From alert@myemail.com -Subject $subject
```

Comment: Good idea taking the email cmdlet out of the loop but this would still have unnecessary cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use Measure-Object but if you want to handle it with your code change it to the following:

```
$greater = $false
$all = 1,10,999,1990,2002,9101,5000,12,500
foreach($cauta in $all){
    if($cauta -gt 7000){
        $greater = $true
        break 
    }
}
if ($greater -eq $true){
Send-MailMessage -To me@myemail.com -From alert@myemail.com -Subject "CRITICAL load" 
}
else{
Send-MailMessage -To me@myemail.com -From alert@myemail.com -Subject "OK load"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Edited the answer